# Displaying Library before a User Keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: java, integration-testing, robotframework

For a Robot Test Case, is it possible to display the User Library that the User Keyword is from?

For example: if the library is com.mycompany.HelloWorld and the User Keyword is sayHello

The test case will be:

**Hello Test    ${variable}     Say Hello**

Can the User library be added as follows:

**Hello Test    ${variable}     HelloWorld.sayHello**

Comment: Yes, but you still have to include the lib in Settings. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible.

This is explained in the documentation: http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.1#specifying-a-keyword-explicitly